# Active view is no longer sorting correctly

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, recent-activity

The active view on the main site is no longer sorting correctly.

[image: main site clipping]

Nor is the meta:

[image: meta site clipping]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a side-effect of our database migration. We had to rebuild a few services after it, so things were down for a while.

Should be all good now!